# How to read a csv file and convert commas from the numbers to dot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, list, csv

I have written this code to read a csv file :

```
    for file_to_open in filename:
        file_path = os.path.realpath(file_to_open)
        path_corrected = file_path.replace("file_mngt", "data")
        opened = open(path_corrected)
        reader = csv.reader(opened, delimiter = ";")
        header = next(reader)
        
        for row in reader:
           print(row)
```

And the result is (for every row) something like this:

```
['8', 'Thorgal', '8,49', '3', '25,47']
```

I would like to convert every comma intro a dot, in every single row.
I looked on the internet but they all say I have to put "decimal = ',' " in the csv.reader and it doesn't work.
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: I see no mention of `decimal` in the `csv.reader()` documentation. I think they were talking about `pandas.read_csv()`

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension and call `replace()` on each element of the list.

```
print([item.replace(',', '.') for item in row])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pandas if you intend to work further with the data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("your/file/path", delimiter=";", decimal=",")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the `pandas` library. It supports all the basic features for working with csv files and this makes it a lot easier.

You can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# read file with comma (,) as decimal separator
df = pd.read_csv(file_to_open, sep=";", decimal=",")

# write to file with dot (.) as decimal separator
df.to_csv("new_output_file.csv", sep=";", decimal=".", index=False)
```

afaik the default [csv.reader](https://cpython-test-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/csv.html#csv.reader) doesn't support comma decimals only dot/points. You'd have to add your own custom `map` or convertion function.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library, it provides lots of data processing primitives and generates ad hoc code under the hood:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

# e.g. without header, returns iterable of lists
rows = (
    Table.from_csv(path_corrected, dialect=Table.csv_dialect(delimiter=";"))
    # here we apply replace to every table cell
    .update_all(c.this().call_method("replace", ",", "."))
    .into_iter_rows(list)
)

# with header, returns iterable of dicts
rows = (
    Table.from_csv(
        path_corrected, header=True, dialect=Table.csv_dialect(delimiter=";")
    )
    .update_all(c.this().call_method("replace", ",", "."))
    .into_iter_rows(dict)
)
```